# This sql runs from a window in Sybase, but when I put it in a stored proc, I get an error on the second insert

Tags: sql, sqlanywhere

I'm trying to figure out why I'm getting an error on the second insert when running this as a stored procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE "DBA"."sp_holdterms"( /* [IN | OUT | INOUT] parameter_name parameter_type [DEFAULT default_value], ... */ )
/* RESULT( column_name column_type, ... ) */
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO "DBA"."ProxReg_Holds"(SELECT "DBA"."ProxReg_IDMaster"."StudNum",
    "DBA"."ProxReg_IDMaster"."BirthDate",
    "DBA"."ProxReg_IDMaster"."LastName",
    "DBA"."ProxReg_IDMaster"."FirstName",
    "DBA"."ProxReg_IDMaster"."MiddleName",
    CURRENT Date AS "DatePlaced",   
    "DBA"."HOLD_IMPORT"."HTYPE" AS "OfficeCode",
    "DBA"."HOLD_IMPORT"."Term1" AS "TermID",
    "DBA"."HOLD_IMPORT"."FLAG ",
    1 AS "Forever",
    NULL AS "Comments",
    'HAT' AS "ChangedBy",
    CURRENT Date AS "ChangeDate",
    NULL AS "ChangeTime",
    CURRENT TimeStamp AS "TimeStamp1"
  FROM "DBA"."ProxReg_IDMaster" JOIN "DBA"."HOLD_IMPORT" ON "DBA"."ProxReg_IDMaster"."StudNum" = "DBA"."HOLD_IMPORT"."STUDNUM")


  INSERT INTO "DBA"."ProxReg_Holds"(SELECT "DBA"."ProxReg_IDMaster"."StudNum",
    "DBA"."ProxReg_IDMaster"."BirthDate",
    "DBA"."ProxReg_IDMaster"."LastName",
    "DBA"."ProxReg_IDMaster"."FirstName",
    "DBA"."ProxReg_IDMaster"."MiddleName",
    CURRENT Date AS "DatePlaced",   
    "DBA"."HOLD_IMPORT"."HTYPE" AS "OfficeCode",
    "DBA"."HOLD_IMPORT"."Term2" AS "TermID",
    "DBA"."HOLD_IMPORT"."FLAG ",
    1 AS "Forever",
    NULL AS "Comments",
    'HAT' AS "ChangedBy",
    CURRENT Date AS "ChangeDate",
    NULL AS "ChangeTime",
    CURRENT TimeStamp AS "TimeStamp1"
  FROM "DBA"."ProxReg_IDMaster" JOIN "DBA"."HOLD_IMPORT" ON "DBA"."ProxReg_IDMaster"."StudNum" = "DBA"."HOLD_IMPORT"."STUDNUM")

  INSERT INTO "DBA"."ProxReg_Holds"(SELECT "DBA"."ProxReg_IDMaster"."StudNum",
    "DBA"."ProxReg_IDMaster"."BirthDate",
    "DBA"."ProxReg_IDMaster"."LastName",
    "DBA"."ProxReg_IDMaster"."FirstName",
    "DBA"."ProxReg_IDMaster"."MiddleName",
    CURRENT Date AS "DatePlaced",   
    "DBA"."HOLD_IMPORT"."HTYPE" AS "OfficeCode",
    "DBA"."HOLD_IMPORT"."Term3" AS "TermID",
    "DBA"."HOLD_IMPORT"."FLAG ",
    1 AS "Forever",
    NULL AS "Comments",
    'HAT' AS "ChangedBy",
    CURRENT Date AS "ChangeDate",
    NULL AS "ChangeTime",
    CURRENT TimeStamp AS "TimeStamp1"
  FROM "DBA"."ProxReg_IDMaster" JOIN "DBA"."HOLD_IMPORT" ON "DBA"."ProxReg_IDMaster"."StudNum" = "DBA"."HOLD_IMPORT"."STUDNUM")

  INSERT INTO "DBA"."ProxReg_Holds"(SELECT "DBA"."ProxReg_IDMaster"."StudNum",
    "DBA"."ProxReg_IDMaster"."BirthDate",
    "DBA"."ProxReg_IDMaster"."LastName",
    "DBA"."ProxReg_IDMaster"."FirstName",
    "DBA"."ProxReg_IDMaster"."MiddleName",
    CURRENT Date AS "DatePlaced",   
    "DBA"."HOLD_IMPORT"."HTYPE" AS "OfficeCode",
    "DBA"."HOLD_IMPORT"."Term4" AS "TermID",
    "DBA"."HOLD_IMPORT"."FLAG ",
    1 AS "Forever",
    NULL AS "Comments",
    'HAT' AS "ChangedBy",
    CURRENT Date AS "ChangeDate",
    NULL AS "ChangeTime",
    CURRENT TimeStamp AS "TimeStamp1"
  FROM "DBA"."ProxReg_IDMaster" JOIN "DBA"."HOLD_IMPORT" ON "DBA"."ProxReg_IDMaster"."StudNum" = "DBA"."HOLD_IMPORT"."STUDNUM")

  INSERT INTO "DBA"."ProxReg_Holds"(SELECT "DBA"."ProxReg_IDMaster"."StudNum",
    "DBA"."ProxReg_IDMaster"."BirthDate",
    "DBA"."ProxReg_IDMaster"."LastName",
    "DBA"."ProxReg_IDMaster"."FirstName",
    "DBA"."ProxReg_IDMaster"."MiddleName",
    CURRENT Date AS "DatePlaced",   
    "DBA"."HOLD_IMPORT"."HTYPE" AS "OfficeCode",
    "DBA"."HOLD_IMPORT"."Term5" AS "TermID",
    "DBA"."HOLD_IMPORT"."FLAG ",
    1 AS "Forever",
    NULL AS "Comments",
    'HAT' AS "ChangedBy",
    CURRENT Date AS "ChangeDate",
    NULL AS "ChangeTime",
    CURRENT TimeStamp AS "TimeStamp1"
  FROM "DBA"."ProxReg_IDMaster" JOIN "DBA"."HOLD_IMPORT" ON "DBA"."ProxReg_IDMaster"."StudNum" = "DBA"."HOLD_IMPORT"."STUDNUM")
END
```

It runs fine from a window in Sybase. What could Sybase be doing differently than the stored procedure?

If it would be helpful, I can post an example of the error that I am getting when running it as a stored procedure.

Comment: Yes, that error message would be very helpful

Comment: [Sybase][ODBC Driver][SQL Anywhere]Syntax error near 'INSERT' on line 22
SQLCODE: -131
SQLSTATE: 42000

Answer (score 0):

try to update statement in the correct format. Remove bracket before select statement and after select statement

insert into databasename.Schema.TableName
select ('ABC','ABC',9);

Comment: Removing the brackets didn't seem to change it

Comment: It works with or without the brackets when I run it in a query window, but if I try to paste it into a procedure window and save, that's when I get the syntax error.